# Restarting Services in Linux after a Server Reboot

Tags: linux, tomcat, nodemanager

So today one of our application servers were restarted due to some issue and after restart we found that our application services were not running.

I want to create one script which will check these below services after a server restart and start them automatically if found stopped:

1st Service with Path : /opt/bea/config/nm/nm-sdi-abc/beaNMctl.sh

2nd service TOMCAT - Path : /opt/apache/tomcat/bin --- Service name startup.sh

Catch here is 1st service can be started with the normal id account that i use.

But 2nd service can be restarted after logging into a different service account on same server and network. Like below:

[x201691@abc bin]$ su - apache

Password:

-bash-2.05b$ cd /

-bash-2.05b$ cd /opt/apache/tomcat/bin/

-bash-2.05b$ ./startup.sh

Can someone help?

Also we are not root users.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a shell script:

```
echo YOUR_PASSWORD | sudo -S su 
cd /opt/apache/tomcat/bin/ 
./startup.sh
```

Save this as a file somewhere you have access and add the following cron entry:

```
@reboot MYPATH/myscript.sh >>  MYPATH/script.log 2>&1
```

script.log will contain any output or errors from your script. You can add `date` command to the script to help with information on when it was run. More information on [cron](https://opensource.com/article/17/11/how-use-cron-linux) here.

Also, if you have concern with putting password in the script, you can go through the discussion [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/69172/how-to-securely-automate-running-commands-as-root-with-sudo-su).

Comment: Hi mbsingh ... I can create a cron job no issue there. What i am looking for is a script that will start 1st service and 2nd service itself when server is rebooted?

Comment: Is there something specific you're looking for in the script? I thought only changing the user ID was an issue which the script above already has. The @reboot at the start of cron entry means the script will be run when the server starts up.

Answer (score 0):

```
Preferred approach when installing Tomcat in Linux is to make Tomcat as a service.

This will ensure your service is started after reboot

1. Create the service file with the following command:     
touch /etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service

2. Assign the relevant rights to the file you created:
    chmod 664 /etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service

3. Paste the following content in the file while adapting it to your configuration:

       [Unit]

       Description=Application description/name

       After=syslog.target network.target

       [Service]

       Type=forking

       User=tomcat

        ExecStart=$CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh

        ExecStop=/bin/kill -15 $MAINPID

        Install]

        WantedBy=multi-user.target


4. Reload the service daemon:  systemctl daemon-reload

5. Start the service:      systemctl start tomcat

6. To check status :      systemctl status tomcat
```